# How to enable netty metrics in Webflux application

Tags: java, netty, spring-webflux, metrics

I call Schedulers.enableMetrics() in application starter and define a bean :

```
@Bean 
public NettyServerCustomizer nettyServerCustomizer() { 
   return httpServer -> httpServer.metrics(true, () -> uriMappingFunction); 
}
```

I am not sure how to write uriMappingFunction. Could you give an example for the simple webflux application ?

Comment: `uri -> uri`. This would do no transformation on the `uri`

Comment: could you give a simple example with transformation?

Comment: And  I still don't see any http server metrics after using 
 0

I call Schedulers.enableMetrics() in application starter and define a bean :

@Bean public NettyServerCustomizer nettyServerCustomizer() { return httpServer -> httpServer.metrics(true,   uri->uri); }

Comment: you can transform it in any way you like. The function definition is `Function<String, String>`. You just need to return a `String`. One use case may be to remove path variables from the uri to avoid cardinality issues in you metrics due to a large set of unique uris.

Comment: If I have many resources in my services  do I need to map each of the resource in this functions?

Comment: it all depends on what you are trying to achieve. The simplest implementation you can provide is `uri -> uri`, as explained above which does no transformation on the uri. Can you try to explain exactly what issue you are having and if possible, provide a reproducible example?